# Android App that uses unitywebrequest does not build although it runs in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

so im working on an app that has to get the location of one's phone and tell the weather.for now i did the script to find its location which works perfectly fine in the unity peview but while trying to build it i am getting several errors such as[image]

the networking code looks as such:
[image]

and the "tara" class is this one:
[image]

pls help

Comment: Im surprised it runs in unity. The docs do not show isError. There is "error" and "isDone" but no isError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are currently checking for errors is no longer correct with the latest version of the UnityWebRequest API. Follow this example instead:

```
using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
        {
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            switch (webRequest.result)
            {
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                    Debug.LogError("Error: " + webRequest.error);
                    break;
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                    Debug.LogError("HTTP Error: " + webRequest.error);
                    break;
                case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                    Debug.Log("Received: " + webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html